# How to add on left side of this top nav responsive menu a text logo?

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, responsive

Am trying to modify the w3c top nav responsive menu in order to put on its left side a text logo (ex. Mylogo) but i dont know how my knowledgle is so poor on responsivness, so please can anybody show me how to make it ?

I want text logo (a word) on the left side of the menu and on the right side to be placed the text links of the menu.

Here is the full code :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an image before the `.topnav` and float it to the left. Set that image to `display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;`.

Comment: hm but i dont want to add an image but text a word par example MyLogo

Comment: You said text logo so I assumed it would be an image. So float a `<div>` or `<p>` with the text in it to the left of `.topnav` with similar attributes to your navigation so it's the same line height etc. Did you not write the code above yourself? It seems if you had, you wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: @erapen  in easy way you can add this line before the li tag which contain home <li  class="logo"><a href="#">My Logo</a></li> so this will take place of home.. And if you set the text before the ul tag you have to set the position for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example. I comment out in my css(span.logo &  ul.topnav li a:nth(1)) where I have changes. You can make it more beautiful when you learn more about. And I see you follow w3school. It's a good site to learn. Good luck mate. If you have any question ask me in comment. :) 
[N.B: This Just an example you will get more when you search on web]

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
span.logo {
  position: absolute;
  /*This set the position absolute for take the My logo text inside the navbar section if you set positon fixed the the text will scroll will your body */
  top: 8px;
  /* Top 8px makes the logo in the middle of the navbar*/
  left: 5px;
  /* left 5px makes the logo get a margin from left border*/
  color: red;
  /* This is the color of text you can set it with your fev color*/
  font-weight: bold;
  /* set the font-weight bold*/
  font-size: 25px;
  /* set the font-size 25px you can change this. but remember if you make it bigger or smaller you need to set the top section so that it will be center with all other li */
z-index:10;   /* Set z-index so that It will display in navbar toggle menu*/
}

ul.topnav li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 100px;
  /*This margin left apply on the li child 1 means the Home text in dextop view*/
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
   
  ul.topnav li {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

   }
```

```html
   

 <body>
 <span class="logo">My Logo</span>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#news">News</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a>
   </li>
   <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would argue against absolute positioning as a solution. It's very brittle and requires a lot of specific values to be set and to be set on other elements other than the text logo element, i.e. `top`, `left` `margin-left`. IMHO line height and some padding would be better than `top` and `left` for positioning the text.

Comment: @hungerstar mate I already said that in my first line "Its just an example " and if I don't set the position absolute. How can I set that span  inside the ul tag which is out side of the ul in my answer? If I don't use position absolute then I have to add some extra html and css.  And you're more experience then me. I would like to learn from you. Not going to argue with you. And thanks for negative mark.

Comment: @hungerstar I guess so.You comment on my answer maybe you don't like my answer. And in this topic no one else place answer or comment. So I guess your the one who give me downvote. If I'm wrong then maybe I will get another downvote after this comment. :P And If your not who give me the downvote then forgive me if I'm blaming you for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an element before the navigation and float it.

In my answer I wrapped the text logo and navigation in a `<header>` element and moved the background color from the `<ul>` to the `<header>`. I also replicated some of the styles used by the navigation (i.e. padding) on the text logo for positioning and styling purposes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.primary-nav {
  background-color: #333;
}
.text-logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<header class="primary-nav">
  <div class="text-logo">My Logo</div>
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
```